# Entity Framework 4 usage with Oracle Db

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

Are there any known issues of EF usage with Oracle database? Are there any key points I should  specially pay attention? Share your toughts and experience please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Devart dotConnect for Oracle](http://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/) allows you a direct access to the Oracle database without Oracle client installation.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a 3rd party EF provider to talk to Oracle, this may cost money.

All of the EF examples asume you are using Sql Server

Answer (score 0):

Most EF implementations for Oracle require the deployment of the Oracle client in order to use some or all of the available features. Look for an implementation that is 100% managed for support of *all* features in order to avoid the performance bottlenecks, memory leaks, and deployment headaches this type of implementation can cause.